# Redirect using mod_rewrite in file .conf is not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

In my server apache, I need to redirect URLs in a .conf file. In my file `http.conf`, located in `/etc/httpd/conf`, one of the lines contains the following configuration:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

In the folder the setting is indicating, in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`, I have a file called `redirect.conf` that has the following redirect code inside:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/?abracar/?$ /abracar? [L,R=301]
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/?presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso/?$ /presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso? [L,R=301]
      RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=2&PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
      RewriteRule ^/?acessorios/confeitaria.html/?$ /acessorios/confeitaria.html? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This code should redirect the URL `https://example.com/abracar?PageSpeed=noscript` to `https://example.com/abracar`, but it is not working. If I put this code in my `.htaccess` file, it will work correctly, but due to external factors, I need to put this redirect into a separate `.conf` file. I have tried several different configurations, I researched a lot about it already, but nothing that could help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest solution would be to drop the query string entirely?!

**Note that QSD requires Apache 2.4 or newer.**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Added a more generalized and easier to comprehend (for humans) version:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

.+ is the generalized form of and query string that isn't NULL. and the RewriteRule now lists all parts of the URL, but I'd stick to ^ %{REQUEST_URI} for the real version, because both versions just rewrite every URL to itself.

Comment: It did not work ... The version of my apache is 2.4.6, so I think it should work normally. Another thing is also that it is not only a URL that will be directed with this parameter, they are several, I added some other examples in the question.

Comment: Edited my answer. The generalisation of %{QUERY_STRING} should be sufficient. Just added the RewriteRule extended version for clarification. But the above does the same...or should do anyway :D

Comment: This works perfectly in my `.htaccess` file, however I can not in it, I need to put it in a `.conf` redirect file inside `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and putting the code in that `.conf` redirect file does not work. `AllowOverride All` is set in my `httpd.conf` file, in addition to the settings described in the question and even then, redirects do not work ...

Comment: Just to be sure: Your httpd.conf contains the line Include conf.d/*.conf and this line comes after the module includes? AllowOverride is a directive specifically for directories. So is it included in a <Directory XYZ>? Doyou get any errors in the error.log? What happens when you activate the rewritelog within the error.log? Can you see why the rule isn't applied? --> How to activate the rewrite logging. LogLevel alert rewrite:trace4   trace4 for almost maximum information (query strings are logged at trace4+)

Comment: Yes, my `httpd.conf` file contains the `Include conf.d/*.conf` line, which comes after the `RewriteEngine On` call, and it comes before the `<Directory XYZ>` configuration call. What I find strange is that I do not get any errors in any log, thus the problem getting somewhat difficult to find. I have already tried several configurations within the `<Directory XYZ>`, with VirtualHost, but nothing works. But, if I do a redirect as the example: `RedirectMatch 301 /test https://example.com` works normally in my `httpd.conf` file or in my other file with redirects inside `conf.d`.

Comment: Wait a second Redirect even works in your seperate /etc/httpd/conf/rewrite.conf file??? Redirect is a directive defined in mod_alias, while RewriteRule and RewriteCond are directives from the mod_rewrite module. Did you include that and restart the Apache?

Comment: The redirects in my separate `/etc/httpd/conf/rewrite.conf` file do not work. These redirects work if I put them in my `.htaccess` file, otherwise no, and in the case, I need to leave those redirects in a separate file without changing my `.htaccess` file and these redirects in that separate file are not working. What you said I included and restarted `Apache` several times.

Comment: Did you turn the rewrite log on with rewrite:trace4 (as written above)? You should be able to see how the request is handled by your Apache. Including all tries of the Apache to match your rules with the request, even if they don't match. That way you can check if your rule is even considered by the Apache. Without any more information I have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: Yes, I've activated the rewrite reconfiguration log: trace4 and I'm analyzing the logs to see if I find anything relevant. How could I have my `.htaccess` inherit the settings from my file in the `conf.d` folder through `RewriteOptions`?

Comment: I'll move the conversion to chat and we'll update with any new information or results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192389/discussion-between-hello-fishy-and-matheus-portela).